# OSX smooth scrolling in tmux

Tags: linux, tmux, osx-yosemite

I'm SSH'ing into a linux box using iTerm2. On that box I run tmux 1.6. I have enabled mouse mode:

`set -g mode-mouse on`

This works fine, and I can scroll when using `tail`, but it's not the same scrolling as if I scroll a `tail` outside of tmux. It's not smooth, and instead moves a cursor - slowly.

I have read numerous posts about getting scrolling to *work* on tmux, but not how to make it smooth. Has anyone succeeded with this?